# TypeScript: cast function call to non-null

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example:

```
const order = await Order.findById(orderId);
```

then:

```
order.thing = something;
```

Warns that `order` may be null.

This can be silenced with:

```
order!.thing = something;
```

My question is: is there a way to specify that the `order` will not be null when initializing it?

e.g. is there something like:

```
const order = await Order.findById(orderId)!;
```

or

```
const order! = await Order.findById(orderId);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of `Order.findById` is presumably `Promise<WhatEver | null>`. So you want to actually use the non-null assertion on the unwrapped value of the promise.

```
// here, typeof order does not include `| null`
const order = (await Order.findById(orderId))!
```